# Behind the scenes of Javascript sort comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, compare, comparison

```
const arr = [3, 89, 1, 120, 23];
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

The code above sorts the array.
However, how does sort know that **a** = current index and that **b** = next index???
We never specify to sort what they are and to what they're equal to.

And after that, how does **.sort** figure out that the returned value from that anonymous arrow function means that the value need to be moved?
**Example:** [1, 2]

```
sort((a, b) => a - b))
sort((1, 2) => 1 - 2))
sort((1, 2) => -1))
sort(-1));
```

See? How does .sort know what to do with -1?

I've been Googling and YouTubing for the past 2 hours and can't find the answer... :(

Answer (score 0):

> However, how does sort know that a = current index and that b = next index?

No, `a` is current value, `b` is next value.
The `sort` function you see is not just run once, it runs again and again, depending on which length your array has.
In your case, in the first run, `a` equals `3` and `b` equals `89`.  And the second run, `a` equals `3`, `b` equals `1`.

The `sort` function is work for an array of strings, so if you need to sort an array of strings, just use `array.sort()`
`Compare function` is required when you need to sort a numeric array.
If not, it gets the wrong result: "25" is bigger than "100", because "2" is bigger than "1".

`Compare function` just return three kinds of number:

1. Negative number (-1,-2,...): it means `a` less than `b`
2. Zero (0): it means `a` equals `b`
3. Positive number (1,2,3..): it means `a` greater than `b`

So, you can more clearly return inside the `Compare function` like this:

```
if(a === b)
    return 0;
if(a < b)
    return -1;
return 1;
```

But, simpler, you can a using a trick, you just need to `return a-b` to determine whether `a` is greater than `b` or not.

See more: [JavaScript Sorting Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)